# MongoDB aggregation project different fields based on the matched condition?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am writing a query in MongoDB using `aggregation` such that if `condition 1` matches then I want to project some fields and when `condition 2` matches I want to project some different fields and when the third `condition 3` reaches I want to project some other different fields.

My Query is like below

```
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {
                {field_a: "henesa"}
            },
            {
                $expr: {
                    $or: [
                        { Condition 1}, {Condition 2}, {condition 3}
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]

    }
},
{$project: { /* Here How To Decide which params to send */}}
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<field>: <expression>` syntax of [$projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#remove-example) at the projection stage.

In `<expression>` part you can use [conditional operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#conditional-expression-operators) to project values based on your criteria. E.g.

```
{ $project: {
    field: { $switch: {
        branches: [
             { case: Condition 1, then: "$field1" },
             { case: Condition 2, then: "$field2" },
             ...
        ]
    } }
} }
```

Or more complex combination of [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) if you need to handle cases when more than one `$or` conditions met.

Comment: In the query which I described documents first matches the query and if the entire query matches then only project the results, but in your case, some docs get rejected in the $project phase, so don't you think it will cause some delay in your query. Because of some documents which get rejected in the $project phase, Which should have been first rejected in the $match phase

Comment: I have updated the answer if it isn't clear that projection stage doesn't replace the whole pipeline. It is an example for `/* Here How To Decide which params to send */}` part of the question. A projection stage doesn't reject anything. It re-shapes documents provided by the previous stage.

Comment: You are writing Conditions in both $project and in $match ?

Comment: Because if you are writing it again then some extra time will be taken again in the $project phase to check if the condition is true or not?

Comment: Yes, conditions in $match and $project stages should be the same. It's why I put the exact conditions you posted in the question. And yes, it will cost you extra CPU ticks db side. If you are asking how to get it for free, you should make it clear in the question. The answer would be plain and simple - you can't.

Comment: Can we set a value in all three conditions and then write $switch for that variable ? because then in project phase mongodb don't have to search for the condition again ? It will be much faster because as in Conditions I am doing elemMatch from Array which will consume much more time than checking for a variable value ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I lost you here. You can "set value"  either on `$addFields` or `$project` stages. Either way you need to apply the same condition to set the value on that extra stage, so I don't see how you are going to make it quicker.

Comment: No, I mean in condition 1 can I set a variable to 1, and in Condition 2 I can set it to 2, and in condition 3 I can set it to 3, then in project stage, we just need to check($switch) for the variable? Because now in Project stage again I don't have to check for the conditions which I have wrote in $match(and because they are using $in, $elemArray those query will take much more time than just to compare a variable value) what do you think about it, got it ?

Comment: Could you elaborate "in condition 1 can I set a variable to 1" part. I don't get it. How exactly you are going to set a variable in a condition? The phrase doesn't make sense to me. You can set a value when condition is met. It is exactly what the $projection stage does in the snippet I provided in the answer.